# Devise destroy_user_session_path doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my ruby on rails application I've a problem for the user logout with devise

I've this navbar:

```
<% if current_user %>
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><%= link_to 'Prova CMS', articles_path %></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">
      <li><%=link_to 'Gestisci Articoli', articles_path %></li>
      <li><%=link_to 'Gestisci Categorie', categories_path %></li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#"><%= current_user.email %></a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <% if current_page?(articles_path) %>
    <ul class="left">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <%= form_tag articles_path, :id => "articles_search" , method: 'get' do %>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :placeholder => "Cerca per titolo"%>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
  </section>
</nav>

<% else %> 

<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
      <h1><%= link_to 'Prova CMS', root_path %></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">
      <li><%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path%></li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

that i render in the application layout of the site (application.html.erb).
In some page the logouts links doesn't works and they generate a Hashtag on the url of the views (for example if i'm on the articles_path localhost:3000/articles the link add # near the /articles -> /articles#)

in the config/initializer of devise this string is uncommented:

```
  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

and in the application.js i've got all the jquery links working fine:

```
    // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ 
    $(document).foundation();
});
```

and for final these are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'show/index'
  root to: "show#index"


  devise_for :users
  resources :categories
  resources :articles

end
```

Comment: If you look at the web browser console, does it show any Java or other errors when you click the logout link? Are any requests being sent to the Rails server that appear in the development.log file?

Comment: The console and the log doesn't show anything but i've found the cause of the error. the code  <a href="#"><%= current_user.email %></a> put a # on the url of the website and with that (i don't know why) devise can't go to the destroy_user_session_path

Comment: View the [solution](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-devise/issues/4)

Comment: <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %> i already implement it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your issue may be related to turbolinks. Try disabling turbolinks for this page to validate whether this is the case. To your body tag add:

```
<body data-no-turbolink="true">
```

I believe that turbolinks is treating your logout link like a standard page link, preventing the actual functionality firing

**EDIT**

If you prove this is the case, focus disabling turbolinks to just the specific link that causes problems and remove the attribute from the body.

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :data => { :no_turbolink => true } %>
```

Comment: YHEA WAS THAT =). But isn't bad to disable turbolinks?

Comment: I've had a lot of trouble with turbolinks so often remove it from my Ajax based projects completely. I edited my answer to say how to disable just on one link.

Comment: if i apply the data-no-turbolinks to the body works.....but not if i add :data => {:no_turbolinks => true } to the link_to rails tag. So for know i'll apply to the body

Comment: Strange. But I'm pleased something worked for you. You could also try adding the data-no-turbolink="true" to the <li> tag surrounding the logout link. Apparently it is supposed to block turbolinks on all elements in the block. That may allow you some of the benefit of the functionality without blocking the whole page.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 7 solution:

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Phil's answer is correct. Rails 6.0.2.2 didn't require me to disable turbolink:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```