# Devise destroy_user_session_path on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to log out a user from a (test) site in production on heroku.

The problem is heroku transforms this `<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>` in a GET `/users/sign_out`

I've tried this `<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :data => { :no_turbolink => true } %>` as suggested here [Devise destroy_user_session_path does'nt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905257/devise-destroy-user-session-path-doesnt-work)

I've found some solutions in reply to  [destroy_user_session_path is triggering GET instead of DELETE in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003891/destroy-user-session-path-is-triggering-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails) but I don't feel comfortable with the answers as I'd like to avoid a GET.

Logout was ok in development, so I checked on https://devcenter.heroku.com/ and made some modifications, but I am still stuck.
I worked on the asset pipeline and added these gems:

```
gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'
gem 'rails_stdout_logging'
```

These gems are probably useful in other cases, but not mine (I also have a problem with links to images that don't persist).

> EDIT

Here is my full template

```
<div class="" style="background-color: #1a252f;">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'Edit account|', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :data => { :no_turbolink => true } %></li>
      <% else %>
         <li class="nav-item">
         <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

> EDIT 2

I've also tried this in routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users do
  get "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

and I still get a status 404 in the heroku logs.

Comment: Can you show us your complete template please?

Comment: Which template do you mean ?

Comment: instead of `rails_ujs` ,   `require jquery_ujs` in the `application.js` file. then precompile the assets.

Comment: Do you mean it's a JS stuff with devise ? I don't use rails_ujs for the time being

Comment: your template (html.erb) where your link is .

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided here: [destroy_user_session_path is triggering GET instead of DELETE in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003891/destroy-user-session-path-is-triggering-get-instead-of-delete-in-rails) was the one for me,
i.e. with `config.sign_out_via = :get` in devise.rb